# Using Parallels, Win 7 and Excel 2010-- Excel restores itself immediately after being minimized

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, parallels

I'm using Excel 2010 in Windows 7, through Parallels on Mac OS X.  Some times, when I go to minimize Excel, after the minimization animation, Excel immediately restores itself.

How can I fix this without closing and re-opening Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is causing this bug (either Parallels or Excel) but I've found that it only occurs while I'm in Coherence mode.  For a long time, I would close Excel and re-open it.  This isn't a big deal if one spreadsheet is open, but if you are floating between 5+ documents, this can be annoying.

The easiest solution I have found is to exit Coherence mode in Parallels, minimize Excel (it should work properly) and then re-enter Coherence mode.  From that point on, minimization of Excel should function properly, at least for a little while.